# Applying T0 Space Rules

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I am starter at Topology. 
I have found a definition of $T_0$ as;
"A topological space $X$ is said to be a $T_0$ space if for any $x,y \in X$, $x \neq y$ there exist an open set $U$ such that $x \in U$ but $y \notin U$"

For $X=\{a, b, c\}$  $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$ is known $T_0$. However, we cannot find any set $S$ such that ; $a \in S$ and $b \notin S$. So, how can above $\mathcal{T}$ be $T_0$? 
Thanks.

Comment: For $T_{0}$ we only need that either there is an open set containing $b$ that does not contain $a$, or that there is an open set containing $a$ that does not contain $b$. I don't like the definition you found, are you sure that's what it says?

Comment: I directly copied the definition, sir

Comment: Ok, then it's just wrong.

Comment: Thank you. It's better I study on a different definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a$ and $b$ we take $S = \{b\}$, then $b \in S$ and $a \notin S$. 
We cannot do it the other way round (any open set that contains $a$ also contains  $b$) but for $T_0$ we only need to be able to do one of them, otherwise the space is called $T_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I understand now. So the thing that I tried to find was T1 and we can say it's not T1. Thank you so much for answers